# ¿Cómo puedo hacer con Javascript un programa que pida un código de seguridad dos veces, hasta que coincida y nos de paso a la aplicación

Tags: javascript, bucles, seguridad, contraseña, alert

También deberá lanzar una alerta que salga al tercer intento en el que las contraseñas no coincidan y que nos indique que hemos agotado todos los intentos.

Lo que yo he hecho es esto:

```
clave1 = 1234;
clave2 = 1234;

    var clave1 = prompt("Por favor, introduzca su Pin");
    console.log(clave1);
    var clave2 = prompt("Por favor, introduzca su Pin");
    console.log(clave2);

if(clave1==clave2){
    alert("Usted se ha logado correctamente");

}else{
    intentos=0
    do{
        alert("sus claves no coinciden, vuelva a intraducirlas")
        var clave1 = prompt("Por favor, introduzca su Pin");
        console.log(clave1);
        var clave2 = prompt("Por favor, introduzca su Pin");
        console.log(clave2);
        intentos++;
        
    }while(clave1!==clave2 && intentos<3) alert("Se terminaron sus intentos");
        
}
```

La cuestión es que cuando no metes los dos codigos iguales y los vuelves a introducir a la siguiente vez iguales, simplemente continúa sin darnos la alerta "Usted se ha logado correctamente" y no se que hacer para que lo haga. ¿Me podéis ayudar, por favor?

Comment: Tienes la comparación y alerta fuera del ciclo, por lo que solo va a funcionar si en el primer intento se introducen las claves correctas. Te recomiendo replantear la lógica para evitar duplicar código y poner todo dentro del ciclo.

Answer (score 0):

```
var intentos = 0;

do {
    var clave1 = prompt("Por favor, introduzca su Pin");
    var clave2 = prompt("Por favor, introduzca su Pin");

    if (clave1 != clave2) {
        alert("sus claves no coinciden, vuelva a intraducirlas")
        intentos++;
    } else {
        alert("Usted se ha logado correctamente");
    }

} while (clave1 !== clave2 && intentos < 3);
```

Debías de introducir toda la lógica dentro del bucle `do-while`. Este bucle ejecuta una primera vez el código que este dentro del `do`, por lo tanto, primero verifica que las claves sean iguales y en caso de que no lo sean empezará a ejecutarse el bucle.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo Funcional:

```js
clave1 = 1234;
clave2 = 1234;
intentos=0;
while(intentos<4)
{
    var clave1 = prompt("Por favor, introduzca su Pin");
    var clave2 = prompt("Por favor, introduzca su Pin");
        
    if(validar_clave(clave1,clave2))
    {
        alert("Bienvenido");
         break;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Error en Clave");
    }
    intentos++;

        if (intentos==3) 
        {
                alert("Has agotado la cantidad de intentos");
                break;
        }   
}


function validar_clave(valor1,valor2)
{
    if(valor1==valor2)
  {
  return true;
  }
  else{
  return false;
  }
}
```

Te coloque una funcion llamada **validar_clave** que verifica si las claves son iguales y si no suma los intentos.

Para cerrar use **break** para cerrar al estar listo o tener el limite de intentos

Answer (score 0):

Quizá no es necesario, pero como está el tag "seguridad" me parece necesario aclararlo:

**De ninguna manera se puede validar una identidad solo en el cliente.**

Aún tomando esto como un ejercicio, supongo que las claves no se validan entre si, se validan respecto de otra, que suponemos que la almacena el sitio en un lugar seguro. Dejando todo eso de lado, supongo que lo que tienes que haces es basicamente todo en el `do`

```js
const clave = 1234;
let intentos = 1;
let acceso = false;

do {

  const clave1 = prompt(`Por favor, introduzca su Pin (${intentos})`);

  const clave2 = prompt(`Por favor, introduzca su Pin (${intentos})`);

  if (+clave1 === clave && +clave2 === clave) {

    acceso = true;
    alert(`Usted se ha logado correctamente en el intento ${intentos}`);

  } else {

    intentos++;
    intentos <= 3 && alert("sus claves no coinciden, vuelva a intraducirlas");
    intentos > 3 && alert("Se terminaron sus intentos");

  }

}
while (intentos <= 3 && !acceso);
```